# Disabling `@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility` for interface's getters/setters

Tags: typescript, eslint

Eslint produces errors with

```js
"@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": [
  "error",
    {
      "accessibility": "explicit",
      "overrides": {
        "accessors": "explicit",
        "constructors": "no-public",
        "methods": "explicit",
        "properties": "explicit",
        "parameterProperties": "explicit"
      }
    }
  ],
```

When I declare this interface (ts 4.3.5)

```js
export interface IFoo {
    get bar(): number;
    set bar(value: number);
}
```

I get these errors

```
@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility: Missing accessibility modifier on get property accessor bar.
@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility: Missing accessibility modifier on set property accessor bar.
```

Packages versions used

```js
"typescript": "4.3.5",
"eslint": "7.32.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.29.2",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.23.0"
```

Is there something I did wrong? Is this not yet supported by eslint?

Comment: What parser are you using? I can't reproduce with the `@typescript-eslint/parser` parser. This rule should only trigger on a `TSParameterProperty`, `ClassProperty`, or `MethodDefinition` ([source](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.29.2/packages/eslint-plugin/src/rules/explicit-member-accessibility.ts#L275-L279)); an accessor in an interface is a `TSMethodDefinition` with the `@typescript-eslint/parser`.

Answer (score 3):

It must help you `"accessors": "off",`

This is my eslint config.

```
`"@typescript-eslint/explicit-member-accessibility": [
          "error",
          {
            "accessibility": "explicit",
            "overrides": {
              "accessors": "off",
              "constructors": "no-public",
              "methods": "explicit",
              "properties": "explicit",
              "parameterProperties": "explicit"
            }
          }
        ]`
```

documentation link https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-member-accessibility.md

[working rule screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1zGK.png)